# Dispose and dealloc semantics in Xamarin

Tags: mono, xamarin, dispose, monomac, xamarin.mac

I have a Cocoa class bound in monomac. If I call `Dispose()` on an instance of that class, should it always invoke `dealloc` on the unmanaged side?

What reasons might there be for `dealloc` not being invoked when the managed class is `Dispose()`ed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispose` on the managed object will call `release` on the native object, not `dealloc` (but it may end up deallocating the object if nobody else has retained it).

Note that calling `Dispose` multiple times will only call `release` once.

**Update**

This turned out to be a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15405) in MonoMac / Xamarin.Mac (which has now been fixed).

Comment: What causes an object to be sent `retain` in managed code? Simply taking a reference to it?

Comment: Whenever a managed wrapper is created for an Objective-C object, `retain` will be called. Then `release` will be called when the managed object is destroyed (or you call `Dispose` manually).

Comment: I have raised bug 15405 in relation to this behaviour... Rolf, any chance you can take a look and let me know if I'm doing something wrong? https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15405